# How can I move a stackexchange entry to another stackexchange server?

Tags: discussion

I see many excellent questions with excellent answers that are closed because the question was asked on the wrong server.

For example: A question was posted on stackexchange.com, but should have been posted on superuser.com.

Is there a way to move the question and all of it's answers to a different site to fix this problem, remove the clutter, and accept more answers?

Answer (score 5):

Moving a question to another stack exchange site is called [*migration*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work), but it has limitations.

1. You cannot do it yourself, but it is done using the same methods than for closing the question. You can always ask the question again on a more suitable site, but the answers won't follow.
2. Older & closed questions won't be migrated.

   > After 60 days, migrations can only be performed by Stack Exchange employees. These are performed only in very, very rare procedural cases and are usually not done on request.

For example, I'm *voting* to migrate this question to `meta.serverfault.com` as it is not a question about managing servers, but a question about how this site works. Soon you might see how migrations work in practice.

Comment: ...and here, in an hour, you see this migrated. 

Answer (score 0):

If there is an closed question on serverfault,

- and it is old enough that it can't be migrated,
- and you are certain it would be a good fit on another site,
- **and it wouldn't duplicate an existing question on the other site**,
- and you have a **substantial bit of new information  to contribute** to the question or answer,

then could just re-ask it on the appropriate site, maybe linking to the older question.